# Can any $n$ real numbers be part of a geometric sequence?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, geometric-series

Ok so, this might be a really silly question, but quite honestly I couldn't find any info about it. So it all begins with a little rather simple question, so I wrote a simple python code, which essentially brute forces step-by-step solutions. The question is Can $x, y, z$ be a part of a geometric sequence? I've noticed a pattern however, for most of the inputs I gave it, it usually took the smallest value from the input, and found a common ratio approaching $1$, ie. $1.001.$ Which effectively approached y and z after multiplying it a lot of times.

Here's an example for input $2,  24$

$24 = 2*12^n$ where $2$ is a, $12$ is r, when we plug it into $ar^n$ we get that $2$ is the first term and $24$ is the second one.

However, aside from that, it spit out many other approximations, such as

$2*1,0001^n$, which also is a very good approximation, and the more time it took to compute the more 0's it added essentially. In here $2$ is the first term, and $24$ is the $24851$st term.

When I let it compute it for an hour with very high approximation it came up with

$2*1,0000001^n$ where $2$ is the first term, and $24$ being $24849068$th term, you get the point.

So now my question is, can any given set of Real positive numbers, with n terms, be expressed as a geometric sequence of $ns*1.0000...1^n$? ns being the smallest nonnegative number?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: If you are allowed to use any real number for $n$, this is true, because $f(x) = ab^x$ will have range all positive real numbers when $a, b > 0$.  In your case, you are allowing only $x = n$, a natural number. In that case, if you make $ab^n$ increase very slowly, then it will eventually get close to the numbers you want. In your example of $2 *1.0001^n$, the sequence for $n = 0, ..., 4$ looks like (rounding a bit) $2.0,2.0002, 2.0004,2.0006, 2.0008,\ldots$; it will eventually get close to the number you desire, as long as that number's not too big.

Comment: I think the answer is no, even when $n=3,$ although I might be overlooking something. Note that taking logarithms of a geometric sequence converts it to an arithmetic sequence, and so we just need non-existence for an arithmetic sequence, which can be obtained by using for example $1$ and $\sqrt 2$ and $\sqrt 3.$ Note that the pairwise distances between these numbers are incommensurable with each other. That is, you can't find a common unit of length such that there is an integer number of such lengths between $1$ and $\sqrt 2,$ **(continued)**

Comment: and also an integer number of the same lengths between $\sqrt 2$ and $\sqrt 3.$ So for an $n=3$ counterexample to your geometric sequence question, use the three numbers $e$ and $e^{\sqrt 2}$ and $e^{\sqrt 3}.$

Comment: For $e$ $e^√2$ and $e^√3$ with limited computational time, it still has managed to take the smallest one, e and make it $e*1,00000001$ e  being again the first term, $e^√2$ being around 41420000th term and $e^√3$ being the 73200000th term the approximations are more rough, as it had to multiply many floats, but It still managed to approximate it with the same technique

Comment: What @DaveL.Renfro is saying is that you can always get as close as you wish by going far enough (even closer than your Python floating point arithmetic can manage), but that there are situations (most, in fact) where you can't have an exact integer answer. I think he should post this as an answer.

Comment: There are two very different questions being conflated here: is it possible to do this *exactly* (no, even for $n=3$, as @DaveL.Renfro describes); and is it possible to do this *approximately* (yes, although the maximum allowed error would need to be precisely specified in order to write down a specific answer).

Comment: The ratios between numbers are integer powers of another number. So if we consider 1, sqrt2, sqrt3 (like dave renfro said) then that clearly won't work. So maybe instead of reals you can simplify it rationals only?

Comment: Yeah okay, @DaveL.Renfro That makes sense now, tysm.

Comment: Can we show that $1,2,\pi$ is not part of any geometric sequence?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The logarithm of a geometric sequence is an arithmetic sequence. Therefore, for three numbers to be contained in a geometric sequence, the logarithms of those three numbers are contained in an arithmetic sequence. Let the three numbers be $a, b,$ and $c.$ They are all contained in an arithmetic sequence if and only if $\frac{c-a}{b-a}$ is rational. Not every real number is rational, so even three numbers are not guaranteed to all be part of the same geometric sequence. We can easily set $\frac{c-a}{b-a}$ to any real number by making $c$ the real number in question, and making $a$ $0$ and $b$ $1$.

However, we can get arbitrarily good *approximations* by geometric sequences. To do that, we can just use the method you used and make the common ratio very close to $1.$ In fact we can even get arbitrarily good *relative* approximations, by log-shifting and using the answer to [this question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4604146/can-we-scale-the-elements-of-a-set-of-real-numbers-so-that-they-are-arbitrarily)

Comment: +1. Two notes to the OP: first, technically in order to get form "not every real number is rational" to "${c-a\over b-a}$ is not always rational" we need to show that every real number can be written as ${c-a\over b-a}$ for some appropriate choice of $a,b,c$, but that's easy. Second, and more substantively, there's no *need* to "go arithmetic." We could just observe that positive numbers $a<b<c$ are part of a geometric sequence iff $$\log_{b\over a}({c\over b})$$ is rational, and again that doesn't always happen. (But arithmetic sequences are easier to think about so "log-shifting" is useful.)

Comment: I apparently rediscovered Dave L. Renfro's ideas.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $1,2,a$ are terms of a geometric progression. If $r$ is the common ratio of the GP, then $2=r^n$ and $a=r^m$ for some integers $m$ and $n$, so $a^n=2^m$ and $a=2^{m/n}$, a rational power of $2$. Therefore, there are only countably many real numbers that can occur in a geometric progression with $1$ and $2$. In particular, there is no geometric progression containing $1$, $2$, and $3$, since $3^n\ne2^m$.

Comment: Good to see that this question is getting more attention...